# gstreamer rtsp stream not readable using VLC, but readable from another gstreamer instance

Tags: c++, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp

How can I create a simple C++ program using OpenCV to stream using rstp so that it can be seen using vlc?
I have been looking many examples but none works.

Thanks

For instance:

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr <<"VideoCapture not opened"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    VideoWriter writer(
        "appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000",
        0,      // fourcc
        30,     // fps
        Size(640, 480),
        true);  // isColor

    if (!writer.isOpened()) {
        cerr <<"VideoWriter not opened"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (true) {

        Mat frame;

        cap.read(frame);

        writer.write(frame);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The video feed can be read using the command line

*gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 

! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=JPEG, payload=26 

! rtpjpegdepay 

! jpegdec 

! xvimagesink sync=0*

However, it **cannot** be opened with **VLC** using the rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000
URL

Comment: and _how_ does that code not work? a [mre] also includes a usable description of the error/issue you get.

Comment: The code works, if you run the command gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 \
! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=JPEG, payload=26 \
! rtpjpegdepay \
! jpegdec \
! xvimagesink sync=0

Comment: AH! so gstreamer can read the stream, but VLC can't? then it's a gstreamer+VLC problem, not an OpenCV problem. I've adjusted the tags. does VLC give any errors (it should)?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.
Here is an improved version of the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
VideoCapture cap("/home/salinas/Descargas/Minions/Minions.avi"); // video file input
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
std::cout << "Video Capture Fail" << std::endl;
return 0;
}

VideoWriter writer;
// Write this string to one line to be sure!!
writer.open("appsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream ",
            0, 20, Size(640, 480), true);
// Comment this line out

Mat img;
while(cap.read(img))
   {
     cv::resize(img, img, Size(640, 480));
     cv::imshow("raw", img);
     writer << img;
     cv::waitKey(25);
    }
```

Now, the problem is that this is not directly read by a program like vcl. You need to run at the same time an instance of [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) (you can download the binaries wo dependencies [here](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server/releases))

It seems like the opencv writer sends the data to the rtsp-simple-server, which redirects the stream to rtsp clients that request it.

Finally, go to vlc and open the url rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream